# Hardware comparison : P4 2,8HT or Atom dual core 2 x 2(HT) x 1,66 Ghz

Tags: debian, performance, hardware, central-processing-unit

i have a dedicated server (on which <10 websites from 10 visitors to 500 visitors per day) :

> PIV 2,8HT
>   2Go RAM
>   1x80 Go SATA 
>   100 Mbs mutualized / 10 Mbs dedicated

for the same price I have another possibility to switch on  :

> Atom Dual Core 510 HT (1,66 Ghz) 
>   4 Go DDR2
>   250 Go SATA 
>   BP 100 Mbs fullduplex

What do you think ? **What would you choose : stay on my P4 dedicated server, or switch on the other server ?** I'm a little afraid of the 1,66 GHz CPU. Am I wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very loaded question... I hate to say.  There are several variables you didn't explain that could all affect the final answer.

What kind of P4?  (socket type? age? etc...)
What OS?
What web-server?
What database server?
Any HTTPS?
Are you concerned about power consumption?
What is your current CPU load on your existing box?
Are there any special background tasks that get run on a schedule?

In general... without knowing more... I would still suggest going with the Atom dual-core over the p4... as having two distinct cores is better than hyper-threading, and the atoms are much more energy efficient & have less heat issues.

Comment: Linux / Debian 5.  P4 2.8 800Mhz . All i know ;) It an old P4.

Databases : Mysql. CPU load is about pretty low (5% - 7% even less.). The task that recquires the most is calculating data using pikiw (like google analystics)

Answer (score 1):

I'd unquestionably go with the Atom. It's in-order, and clocked lower, but it's also multithreaded and doesn't have the horribly long pipeline that the P4 did to achieve high clock speeds. I'm betting that it would be paired with faster RAM in this case too.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark benchmark and benchmark. Test your own scenario. If it's a rental, ask for a trial for a day/month.

If it's with a different firm, keep in mind the network can differ quite a bit.